# Compiler error when using constexpr and lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda, constexpr

I encountered a problem when using constexpr functions together with lambdas.
The following code is a minimal version which reproduces the error:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned bar(unsigned q) {
    return q;
}

template<unsigned N>
unsigned foo() {
    return N;
}

template<typename F>
void print(F f) {
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}

template<unsigned Q>
int stuff() {
    constexpr unsigned n = bar(Q);
    print([]() { return foo<n>(); });
}

int main() {
    stuff<13>();
}
```

When compiling with `gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)` there are the following compiler errors:

```
constexpr_template.cpp: In lambda function:
constexpr_template.cpp:24:9:   instantiated from ‘stuff() [with unsigned int Q = 13u]::<lambda()>’
constexpr_template.cpp:24:2:   instantiated from ‘int stuff() [with unsigned int Q = 13u]’
constexpr_template.cpp:29:12:   instantiated from here
constexpr_template.cpp:24:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo()’
constexpr_template.cpp:24:32: note: candidate is:
constexpr_template.cpp:9:10: note: template<unsigned int N> unsigned int foo()
```

Now the strange part is, if `constexpr unsigned n = bar(Q);` is changed into `constexpr unsigned n = Q;` it works.
What is also working is `print([]() { return foo<bar(Q)>(); });`...

Is this a bug in GCC or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Try a newer version of GCC (4.7 or 4.8) or Clang.

Comment: Works with clang. Same error with gcc 4.7

Comment: Too much C++ for gcc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gcc 4.6 was [the first version to support constexpr](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport), and it is not unusual for minor bugs to be present upon release of such features. You can verify [from this Live Example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d307020e355b05674bf894719c0e61a3-dec9c2080103b7179bfc01f4ef6097b5) that gcc 4.8.1 and Clang 3.4 SVN correctly parse your code. You probably should upgrade your compiler accordingly.

Comment: @Danvil what did you expect from using a pre-C++11 Standard compiler? curent gcc 4.8 behaves similarly wrt C++14, so in three years that version is also ancient ;-) My rule of thumb: gcc 4.6 = alpha, 4.7 = beta, 4.8 = rtm